# How to resolve Cluster account permission issues

Tags: sql-server, clustering

Can anyone advise please?

I am in the process of creating a **SQL 2016 SP2 SQL FCI**. The WSFC was created by the server team and handed over to me. I ran the cluster configuration validation tests and got the following warning:

*"The cluster network name xxx does not have Create Computer Objects permissions on the Organizational Unit OU=xxx .... This can result in issues during the creation of additional network names in this OU"*

As it was only a warning, I decided to attempt the SQL installation regardless. On first attempt, it wouldn't let me create the SQL Cluster virtual network name until the Domain admin gave me the create computer objects rights in AD. After that I passed that stage and ran the installation to the end. However, at the tail end I got an error:

*"Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Service Features.
The cluster resource 'SQL Server' could not be brought online due to an error bringing the dependency resource 'SQL Network Name (abc)' online. Refer to Cluster Events in the Failover Cluster Manager for more information. Error code:0x86D80058"*

**Cluster Events:**
*Cluster network name resource failed registration of one or more associated DNS name(s) because the access to update the secure DNS Zone was denied.
Cluster Network name: 'Cluster Name'
DNS Zone: 'xyz*'

Ensure that cluster name object (CNO) is granted permission to the Secure DNS Zone.

So, from my research, it would seem that the warning given by the cluster configuration validation tests is the cause of the problem.  My question therefore is how to fix the problem. Does the server admin's account used in creating the windows cluster need to be a domain admin? Or just giving them create computer objects is enough? I think they already have create computer objects, so I'm not sure if they need to be domain admins? Will giving them Read All Properties in addition to Create Computer objects fix the issue? Kindly advise please.

Lastly, when the correct permission has been given, how do I fix the errors in the SQL installation? Do I need to uninstall it or is there a quicker way? What impact could uninstall have when I come to re-install. Is there anything I need to watch out for in uninstalling?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plase, try granting the *Create Computer objects* permission to the cluster name machine object at the OU level. (the OU where you placed the cluster machine object)

[image]

Make sure the cluster machine Object has been granted the Read all Properties permission.

[image]

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731002(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

If you are facing again the DNS registration error, that can come from differente sources.
One common case is that  there is a static DNS reservation on the domain controller.

- Identify the source of the static reservation and try to ensure that
  this does not happen again. Cluster DNS records should be dynamic.
- Identify the static DNS record in your Active Directory Integrated
  DNS forward lookup zone. Ask for help from your DNS or AD team if
  necessary.
- Delete the static record Take the Cluster Name Object
  representing the DNS record offline in Failover Cluster manager. Be
  aware that any dependent resources will also go offline.
- Bring everything back online. This should trigger a new DNS registration
  attempt. You could also wait for the cluster to attempt this
  automatically, but client connections may fail while you are waiting.
- Verify that the DNS record is created as a dynamic record. It should
  have a current Timestamp.

Comment: thank you very much, I will get the Domain admin to try this tomorrow and I will feedback. Thanks again for your time, much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks again @MBuschi, I think granting those permissions worked but only up to a point. For some reason the Validation tests passed but Cluster events errors persisted. I was able to do the installation but SQL warned that there were cluster validation errors even though the installation completed successfully. We are still working on it. I will let you know how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking but do you see any problem, if we remove the secondary node and use the instance a stand alone on only one node? To use it this way, does WSFC still have to be in place or do we have to remove the windows clustering as well?

Comment: I added an hits about DNS error but without additiona logs i can't be sure about the issue you are facing.
About the clustering you have to keep in place FCI even with a single node.
At the end if you install everything with a Domain Admin account it should go.

Comment: Thanks again @MBuschi.  Are there additional logs that I should be looking at apart from Cluster Manager Cluster Events and usual errorlog? Cluster Events gives following message: Cluster network name resource failed registration of one or more associated DNS names(s) because the access to update the secure DNS Zone was denied.

Cluster Network name: 'SQL Network Name (xxx)'
DNS Zone: 'xyz'

Ensure that cluster name object (CNO) is granted permissions to the Secure DNS Zone.

Comment: Nothing else. Try to solve the dns issue as above. If it does not work redo the installation with DA rights

Comment: To be more precise you must have these rights:

To create a failover cluster, you must be a local administrator with permissions to log on as a service, and to act as part of the operating system on all nodes of the failover cluster instance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/create-failover-cluster#verify-the-prerequisites

Comment: Thank you so much @MBuschi, the issue got resolved by removing the SQL Telemetry service. I do not understand how that service would have stopped the cluster running? Thanks all the same for all your time, very much appreciated

Comment: I did not select the box for Error reporting during the installation, would you know how it could have been installed? Does it behave differently in a cluster than a standalone, I'd never had an issue with that service before?

Comment: Error reporting is not Telemetry Service. I never had this kind of problem. It should be the same as standalone install...

Comment: thanks again. Is it not the same as error reporting? I thought that was what I got from my research? What is it then? It is still a puzzle to me how it got installed on the server. The cluster installation was successfully verified the previous day. Thank you all the same for all your time.

Comment: thanks again for your time. Believe it or not, I tried the installation again myself and the cluster ran successfully until I rebooted one of the servers and it just wouldn't come back up until the CEIP Resourse was removed in Cluster Manager.!! Strange but I confirmed it myself from start to finish. Thanks again.